# How to fetch each td containits in a table, using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am generating a table dynamically.

I want to fetch all of my TD containts, excluding Thead containts.

My table looks something like this:

```
<Html>
<table id="tblPhone">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Type </th>
      <th> Primary </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Gen </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" CHECKED /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Mob </td>
      <td> <input type="radio" /> </td>
    </tr>
....
....
  </tbody>
</table>
</Html>
```

I need to fetch the data & fill to my below class (C#):

```
class TelephoneType
{
  public string Type;
  public bool Primary;
}
```

I ve used the below JS function in a Button click, but its not working :(.

```
function RetriveTelephoneData() {

    var obj = $("#tblPhone");

    var hasTH = obj.find("thead").size() > 0;
    var hasTBody = obj.find("tbody").size() > 0;

    if (obj.is("table") && !hasTH) {
        var widths = [];

        // capture widths before rearranging
        obj.find("tr td").each(function(i) {
            widths.push($(this));
        });
    }
}
```

I am new to Jquery. Please help me to solve the issue.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Dont know why my table is not rendering as I typed :(

Comment: That's not javascript. That looks like java.

Comment: I was able to fix it.  Use the code button (represented by a `{}` button in the editor)

Comment: You have no tries and no bugs. You just are asking for us to do something for you because you don't feel like trying... Go ahead and set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Get as close as you can to selecting all the table elements then we can help.

Comment: I ve tried, but have not mentioned my JS function before. Now I ve edited my question to mention that too.

Comment: //capture widths before rearranging :D where did you copy this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as your button click code:

```
function Telephone(type,primary)
{
    this.Type=type;
    this.Primary=primary
}

function RetriveTelephoneData(){
    var phones=[];
    $("table#tblPhone > tbody > tr").each(function(){
    var tds=$(this).find("td");
    var t=new Telephone($(tds[0]).text(), $(tds[1]).find("input:radio").is(":checked"));
    phones.push(t);
}
```

First of all create a js class to capture values. next loop over all rows in `tbody` and find `type' and`primary`value of phone to create object of`Telephone` class and push it to array. Now you can do whatever you like with contents of the array.

PS:- you need to put `name` attribute on your radio buttons (with same value like `name='primary'`.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `<td>` in your `<thead>` use `<th>`.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Column1</th>
       <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td> 0,1</td>
       <td> 1,1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

etc...

```
var allTd = $('td');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function RetriveTelephoneData() {

    //var obj = $("#tblPhone");

    //var hasTH = obj.find("thead").size() > 0;
    //var hasTBody = obj.find("tbody").size() > 0;

    //if (obj.is("table") && !hasTH) {
        var widths = [];

        // capture widths before rearranging
        $("#tblPhone").find("td").each(function(i) {
            widths.push($(this).width());
        });
    //}
}
```